# What happens to temp files in Heroku (Node application)

Tags: node.js, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a free Heroku account and my Node app uses Amazon S3 to store files. I ham using s3fs module along with multiparty-middleware which first temporarily stores the files and then uploads it to S3.

After the file is uploaded and unlinked in fs, the file still remains in my local temp folder during local development. I have deployed the same code on my Heroku app and I am worried if there is any way to check the temp folder or delete it daily because the app has slug size limit of 500mb and the uploaded files can be even more than 100s of Mbs.

Answer (score 2):

In Heroku, each dyno has its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code.

In general, the ephemeral filesystem works just like any filesystem. Directories you have permission to write to, such as `/tmp`, you can write files to.

During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad and any files written will be discarded at the moment the dyno is stopped, restarted or recycled.

If you are storing your temp files in `/tmp` folder you can run `df` to check used and available space:

```
heroku run bash
df -h /tmp
```

Also note that the slug is a compressed and pre-packaged copy of your application and files are not stored inside the slug but in the ephemeral filesystem of your dyno. It's highly unlikely that you have a use case that really justifies having to delete files from your dyno's ephemeral filesystem.

In conclusion, you should not worry about deleting the `tmp` folder daily since any files written will be discarded at the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted or approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to process the file before uploading to S3, that's why it is being stored temporarily. I won't be having any problem until Heroku starts charging for it. The files in temp are useless after uploading to S3 and I fear in between the dyno restart, the app will collect temp data up to few GBs.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, i have the same use case for the ephemeral storage (it will serve only when the file is being processed). did you have to delete the files created temporarily ? thank you